# Which Checkout event should I use to execute code after product is added to cart?

Tags: product, event-observer

I'm working on Magento CE 1.9 and I would like to execute the following code after the customer adds a product to cart:

```
<?php
$id = '226'; // Replace id with your product id
$qty = '1'; // Replace qty with your qty
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
$cart->init();
$cart->addProduct($_product, array('qty' => $qty));
$cart->save();
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
?>
```

The above code will programmatically add a product to cart. Ultimately, I'm going to test to see if the conditions of a shopping cart price rule are met and if so, run that could which adds a free "gift" or promotional product.

I've got my basic module configured. I'm just curious which event I should make use of that will allow me to add a product and update the cart? These appear to the applicable options:

- checkout_cart_add_product_complete
- checkout_cart_product_add_after
- checkout_cart_update_items_before

So everytime a product from my catalog is added, an event is fired and my code is executed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should go for `checkout_cart_add_product_complete` (which is run in the `addAction` of the CartController). `checkout_cart_update_items_before` isn't appropriate for the action you're describing, and `checkout_cart_product_add_after` is triggered on `addProduct`, which will cause an issue because you are using this exact function in your observer.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `controller_action_postdispatch_cart_index_add` and check wheather your condition matches and add your code to add product to cart

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that. Some modules (ajax Add to Cart f.e) use customer controllers. Which means this one wouldn't be executed any more.